# When i try install requests give me this error

Tags: python, pip, python-requests

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
aiohttp 3.8.3 requires charset-normalizer<3.0,>=2.0, but you have charset-normalizer 3.0.1 which is incompatible.
```

I trying to install requests

Comment: When and where did you install `charset-normalizer` in the first place? Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], [look for existing solutions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) first, and **ask a question** - don't just describe a task and show an error message.

Comment: can you pip freeze and show us the output as well

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

two packages have the same file name.
The easiest solution is to create a virtual environment for your project:

**How to create a Virtual Environment?**

Just run the below commands one by one:-

```bash
python -m venv .venv
.venv/scripts/activate
pip install request
```